# sql search in a date column from current date to current date+7 not working

Tags: sql, date

This query works and brings up proper results:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WJ07LG4.appointments 
WHERE start >= current_date and start <= '2020-12-17';
```

This query brings up no results even though there are dates within a week of now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM WJ07LG4.appointments 
WHERE start >= current_date and start <= current_date + 7;
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong?

Comment: What is your _version_ of SQL (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT * 
FROM WJ07LG4.appointments 
WHERE start >= current_date and start <= DATEADD(dd, 7, current_date );
```

More info [DATEADD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

You may verify if the data type for both the 'current_date' and 'start' column is either of Date, DateTime,  DateTime2, or SmallDatetime.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried dateadd, and it told me that the function does not exist. I am working in MySQL workbench if that helps. The editor suggested date_add, I tried this, but I get a select is not valid at this position error as if there is something wrong with the expression.

Comment: SELECT * FROM WJ07LG4.appointments WHERE start >= current_date and start <= date_add(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY);    this worked, you gave me the right function, I just had to look up how to format it, ty

Comment: For mysql DATE_ADD(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY) should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM WJ07LG4.appointments 
WHERE start >= current_date and start <= date_add(current_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

is what solved it. subodh led me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

If you just select the results, you can se what is happening:

```
current_date     current_date + 7
2020-11-29       20201136
```

Hmmm, Nov. 36?  What date is that?  Oh!  What is happening is that the database is converting the "date" to an integer and just adding 7.

The simplest solution is to use interval arithmetic:

```
current_date + interval 7 day
```

In your code, that looks like:

```
WHERE start >= current_date AND 
      start <= current_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I am still learning. its good to know.

Comment: @auotive . . . This is tricky, but if you get in the habit of using `interval` you won't have problems.